# Is this a Red-Black Tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I tried to build RBT (Red-Black Tree) via this way:
I build a **balanced** binary search tree (much as I can) and then colored it...

Now the Q is: if this is a legal RBT?
[image]

At my opinion is yes, because all the benefits of RBT are the tree:

1. The root is black.
2. There is two red vertices one after another.
3. The Black-Height is as need to be at a RBT.

If I miss something and it's not a legal RBT I'll be glad if you will correct me and tell me why...

Thank you!

Comment: That is an awful way to draw it, the elements are meant to be ordered.

Comment: @SuzuHirose, why awful? The elements are ordered, no?? I glad to know if I miss something... Thank you!

Comment: @SuzuHirose The elements are ordered in the tree. It's a perfectly good red black tree.

Comment: Elements 5,6,7 and 8,9,10 are not ordered. They are in a vertical line. I don't know what the reason for the contortion with the 7 is. If 7 was to the right and 8 to the left it would be OK but deliberately aligning things which are meant to be ordered is ridiculous, considering the whole point of the data structure is to store an ordered list.

Comment: @SuzuHirose, Oh, if it's about the "place on the board" of the vertices it's because I used LyX and I shrink the graph to save place (otherwise it was hard to draw and maybe not fit the A4 page...). But, thank you for your comment!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a legal RBT but the point of the RBT is that the insert and delete operations are O(log n), in your approach this may not be true. Whether your approach is always colourable in this way - I am not sure.